# MySQL - detecting and handling Lock Wait Timeout inside Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, locking

## The Question

purely for academic reasons, I'm wondering if you could add a handler to a mysql stored procedure that is able to recover from a lock wait timeout error if one of its queries locks up (such as a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `UPDATE`) query.

---

## The Example

This is assuming an innoDB database, set to issolation level `Repeatable read`, with an empty `users` table defined.

### 1. Example Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lock_test`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `lock_test`(OUT status ENUM('success','timeout'))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

        SELECT * FROM `users` FOR UPDATE;
        SET status := 'success';

    COMMIT;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

### 2. Run code in mysql terminal 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM `users` FOR UPDATE;
```

- the contents of `users` will be displayed, but the transaction will remain open.

### 3. Run code in mysql terminal 2:

```
CALL `lock_test`(@out);
SELECT @out;
```

- the transaction will run until it times out (default value of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is 50 seconds)

---

Is it possible to add a handler inside the `lock_test()` procedure, so that we can have @out hold 'timeout'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time reading through the [MySQL Handler Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) I was able to get what I was looking for:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lock_test`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `lock_test`(OUT status_out VARCHAR(255))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE procedure_attempts INT DEFAULT 5;
    DECLARE query_timeout INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    SET status_out := 'start';

    procedure_loop:
        REPEAT
            BEGIN
                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1205
                -- Error: 1205 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
                    BEGIN
                        SET query_timeout := TRUE;
                        SET status_out := CONCAT(status_out,'-timeout');
                    END;

                IF ( procedure_attempts < 1) THEN
                    LEAVE procedure_loop;
                END IF;

                START TRANSACTION;

                    SELECT * FROM `users` FOR UPDATE;

                    IF (query_timeout) THEN
                        SET query_timeout := FALSE;
                    ELSE
                        SET status_out := CONCAT(status_out,'-success');
                        SET procedure_attempts := 0;
                    END IF;

                COMMIT;

                SET procedure_attempts := procedure_attempts - 1;
            END;
        UNTIL FALSE END REPEAT;
    -- loop
    SET status_out := CONCAT(status_out,'-end');
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

When run as follows:

```
SET @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout:=1;
CALL `lock_test`(@out);
SELECT @out;
```

The output will be `start-timeout-timeout-timeout-timeout-timeout-end` after about 10 seconds of running time (which would be much longer if run without setting the timeout to 1 second.

While probably not too practical (or advisable) in most projects, could potentially be useful when debugging timeout issues when running a query from inside another query - I hope it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: The instructions 'MODIFIES SQL DATA' was fixed problem in my giant procedure with lots of delete instructions (in different tables). Thanks.